# I'm trying to run qtSPIM simulator using c code but it always cause error

Tags: c, mips, qtspim

I made assembly code from c code using gcc mips compiler but it does not work in SPIM simulator.
How can I success to run SPIM?
Or is there any other method to obtain assembly code fit to SPIM?

Comment: Do you have [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: SPIM does not implement every feature of the GNU assembler. So your choices are 1) Modifying the generated assembly by reading the documentation for SPIM and GAS, in order to be able to determine what you simply can remove, and what you need to rewrite (and how). Or 2) Just write the code yourself from scratch, using only features available in SPIM.